# Design of Experiments through Algebraic Statistics

Tags: r, experiment-design, software, algebraic-statistics

I would like to ask you about how to compute a circuit basis of a design matrix in software R.

Let me explain: I have found a software, named [Macaulay2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/m2r/readme/README.html), that calculates some algebraic tools, and one of them is circuits. In this program, first of all I load the package `FourTiTwo`, then I define a matrix and finally through the command `toricCircuits` I compute the circuit basis of the matrix. The circuit basis is a subset of Groebner basis.

I know that there is a package of Macaulay2 in R, named `m2r`, but I don't know how to use it for finding that circuit basis.

Is that package the one that I need? Should I use another package? And which is the code about how to compute the circuit basis of a matrix?